Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first in React
So, when a message comes from socket io, when I say to play the audio, it is outputting the following message
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first
This is my code:
useEffect(() => {
    const handleNewOrder = () => {
      audio.play()
    };

    socketMe?.on("all_orders", handleNewOrder);

    return () => socketMe?.off("all_orders", handleNewOrder);
  }, [socketMe]);


I fix the problem with hasUserInteracted below, but my code then only emits a sound when I click the button:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio('your-audio-file.mp3')); // Preload audio
  const [hasUserInteracted, setHasUserInteracted] = useState(false);
  const [pendingEventData, setPendingEventData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleNewOrder = (data) => {
      if (hasUserInteracted) {
        audio.play(); // Play audio immediately if user interacted
      } else {
        setPendingEventData(data); // Store event data for later
      }
    };

    socketMe?.on("all_orders", handleNewOrder);

    return () => socketMe?.off("all_orders", handleNewOrder);
  }, [socketMe, hasUserInteracted, audio]);

  const handleUserInteraction = () => {
    setHasUserInteracted(true);
    if (pendingEventData) {
      audio.play(); // Play audio if pending event data exists
      setPendingEventData(null); // Clear pending data
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleUserInteraction}>Click to Enable Sounds</button>
    </div>
  );
}


**I need it to sound when a new message (i.e. order) arrives, not when a button is pressed. Can anyone help with this problem?
**

If there is a way to automatically click the button when a message (ie order) arrives, please write to me
